# Using GPT fdisk utility produces error

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, boot-camp, macos-highsierra, gdisk

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on the following hardware:

- Mac Mini (late 2014)
- Running MacOS High Sierra

I have disabled SIP and confirmed that it is disabled.
When I run the command in Terminal: sudo gdisk /dev/disk1 I receive the error:

```
Problem opening /dev/disk1 for reading! Error is 16.
```

Does anyone have a solution to this hybrid MBR GUID disk issue which is preventing me from installing Windows 10 on my Mac mini?

Comment: Do you have a `/dev/disk1`? In other words, how many drives do you have and which are internal verses external?

Comment: Why are not you using the Boot Camp Assistant? Why do you need `gdisk`?

Comment: Michael: To insure I am notified that you posted a comment, you need to include a @DavidAnderson somewhere in your comment. I had no idea you were trying to contact me.

Answer (score 2):

The standard procedure for installing Windows 10 to a Mac Mini (late 2014) is to use the Boot Camp Assistant application. The installation does not require the use of a hybrid MBR GUID disk, so this will not be an issue. The partitioning is taken care of by the Boot Camp Assistant application, so there is no need to use `gdisk`. The Boot Camp Assistant application has the necessary permissions to modify any partitions protected by System Integrity Protection (SIP), so there is no need for SIP to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

David, I tryied to use boot camp first, of course it would be the best option. But the Boot Camp installation failed when Windows rebooted to install the Windows files because it refused to format the disk properly. Researching this issue is what brought me to the gdisk procedure.

I resolved this: Boot Camp worked up to the format disk in Windows installation, so I formatted to FAT32. Boot camp refused to continue, I assume due to the hybrid GPT/MBR issue. Since Boot Camp did create a bootable USB, I booted from the EFI partition using Option at bootup. This time, the disk format portion of Windows installation allowed me to format to NTFS and the installation finally succeeded. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: ...and you are right to ask about “disk/disk1” as Boot Camp/Windows Installation will hang up if additional USB drives or disks other than the installation disk are connected. Thanks again!